# Registry permissions problem

Tags: permissions, installation, registry

I need to install an application (SQL Server Denali, but this is irrelevant) and during the installation, I have a lot of problems with registry... a lot of pop-ups appear telling that i dont have permissions to modify that key of the registry.

I'm administration but seems that with some keys i dont have permission and i have to modify permissions manually. The problem is that there is a lot of registers giving problems.

What can I do? How can i add full control to all the keys of the registry?

I have Windows 7 64bits

Thanks

Comment: I think this should go to serverfault...

Comment: Which key (address at registry) you try to use? Please, write it here.

Answer (score 1):

What's your OS on which you are trying to install?

I have seen security features on Windows 2008 and Windows 7 (which is good but can be annoying as seen by you on popups for permissions). Even though the local user is as administrator with which you are trying to install, on these systems its best to right click and choose "Run as Administrator"

Also you can choose to lower the security level on "user account control settings" (click on start menu button in Windows 7 / 2008) and in the search bar type uac, and lower the security to never notify and bring it back up after the installation.

Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks for the answer but I already have the security notify to never... and it didnt work. I continue to have registry problems during the installation. I have Windows 7